# sqlite3: can table name replaced with?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

How can I replace table name with ? ,like this:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists ?（id integer,name text）",(tablename,))
c.execute("INSERT INTO ? (id) VALUES(1)",(tablename,))
```

Comment: That is to say...How can I operate different tables with one function

Comment: Placeholders only work with values, not table or column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
renameTable = "ALTER TABLE old RENAME TO new"

cursor.execute(renameTable)
```

Comment: But how can I replace the table name when I insert?

Comment: You can tun INSERT INTO with new table name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you, I have figured out that I can do like this:

```
str = "INSERT INTO %s(id) VALUES (1)"
c.execute(str%s)
```

Table name can not be replaced by: ?